# Workspace - Filter Add-ons Question (2.80 and 2.81)

Tags: interface, add-on, workspaces

If I enable the new workspace filter add-ons feature, some add-ons that I have enabled in Blender preferences window do not show up in the filter panel. For example, I have the import AutoCAD DXF add-on enabled in the Blender preferences window but it doesn't show up in the workspace filter add-ons panel.

[image]
[image]

The result is that it isn't available in the file import formats list. Does this feature have to be supported in each add-on or am I missing something? Are there any workarounds other than creating another workspace just for importing various file types? Thanks.

Comment: The issue is that in `WORKSPACE_PT_addons`(`properties_workspace.py`) the listed add-ons are checked for `use_owner` key in their `bl_info`. The import and export add-on don't have this set, which is why they get excluded when `use_filter_by_owner` is set to true (the checkbox next to "Filter Add-ons"). I'm not familiar with this part of the code, therefore I'm not sure why the import export add-ons don't have an owner.

Comment: Thanks. I created a separate workspace just for imports and exports. Maybe it will get sorted out in a future release.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick workaround, you could change the "category" in the bl_info section to one of the supported ones. Though "Import-Export" is listed as supported for filtering, it currently is not.

You should be able to filter them after changing, good for maintain addons via workspace.

[image]